# Convergence of the sequence $a_{k+2} = \sqrt{a_{k+1}}+\sqrt{a_k}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of positive reals, such that

$a_{k+2} = \sqrt{a_{k+1}}+\sqrt{a_k},\,\,\forall\,\,k\ge1.$

Prove that the sequence is convergent and compute its limit.

Comment: what is $a_1$ or $a_0$?

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 4$.

Comment: Does he really need initial conditions? He said that the sequence is of positive reals. Maybe you can always prove the claim for any values of $a_1$ and $a_0$

Comment: I do not think that we need initial conditions to solve the problem.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Doen't matter Doktor. The lim is always $4$. Ok initial values have to be positive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit is the number $a$ such that $a_{k+2} = a_{k+1} = a_{k} = a$:

$$a = \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a} \Rightarrow a = 2\sqrt{a} \Rightarrow a = 4.$$

There are many ways to prove (or disprove) the convergence of this sequence to $a$ starting from any initial condition. One of these ways is to study the linear stability of this system. First of all, let's introduce 
$$b_k = a_{k+1}.$$

Then, you can write the relationship in the following way:

$$\begin{cases}
a_{k+1} = b_k\\
b_{k+1} = \sqrt{a_k} + \sqrt{b_k}
\end{cases}$$

Thereafter, in order to study the linear stability of this system, you must linearize it around the limit point $[a, a]$ (notice that also the limit of $b_k$ is $a$). The most important (and most informative for convergence) part of the linearization is given by the Jacobian matrix:

$$ J(a_k, b_k) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial a_{k+1}}{\partial a_{k}} & \frac{\partial a_{k+1}}{\partial b_{k}}\\
\frac{\partial b_{k+1}}{\partial a_{k}} & \frac{\partial b_{k+1}}{\partial b_{k}}\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a_k}} & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{b_{k}}}\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now, you must evaluate the Jacobian in the limit point (that is, $J(a_n = a, b_n=a)$):

$$ J(4, 4) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The final part requires the calculation of the eigenvalues of $J(4,4)$, which are

$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{17}}{8}.$$

Numerically, these eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 \simeq -0.39$ and $\lambda_2 \simeq 0.64$.
Since:

- There is no eigevalue such that $|\lambda| = 1$
- All eigenvalues are such that $|\lambda| < 1$

then, thanks to the [Hartman–Grobman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem), you can conclude that $a$ is a convergent limit point. Quite sure it is also a global attractor WRT to the set of initial conditions $\{(a_0, a_1) : a_0 > 0 \wedge a_1 > 0\}$.

Comment: Global attractor if the $a_k > 0$, not sure if this is true for negative values...

Comment: Nice idea to turn into a system, would not have approached it this way.

Comment: @Gregory Of course, in my mind I'm working with $a_0 > 0$ and $a_1 > 0$, as well as $a_n > 0 ~\forall n$

Comment: @Gregory Converges to $a=4$ also for negative initial values. Converges even if one of the two initial values is zero. Just experimented with $a_1=0;\;a_2 =10^{-10}$ and I got $a_{20}\approx 3.981$

Comment: @Raffaele $a_1 = 0$ and $a_2 = 10^{-10}$ are **non negative**, but not **negative**!!!

Comment: @the_candyman Converges to $a=4$ also for negative initial values like $a_1=-2;\;a_2=-3$, for instance $a_{20}\approx $3.99912\, +0.00343411 i$. 
 Converges even if one of the two initial values is zero is another thing I was talking about. Thanks God despite my paleolithic age I can still distinguish positives from negatives

Answer (score 5):

I would propose a simpler approach:

1. Since $a_n \geq a_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$, the given sequence cannot stay in the interval $(0,1)$ for too long, in particular $a_n\geq 1$ for any $n$ large enough;
2. The map $x\to\sqrt{x}$ is a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) if $x\geq 1$;
3. $a_{k+3}-a_{k+2} = \sqrt{a_{k+2}}-\sqrt{a_k}$ then implies that $\{a_k\}_{k\geq 0}$ is a Cauchy sequence;
4. $a_k\to L$ clearly implies $L=4$.